# Аналог $_GET/$_POST из PHP в Ruby

Tags: ruby

Доброго времени суток Друзья! Я не плохо знаю PHP, но всё чаще и чаще убеждаюсь в том, что есть языки программирования, которые быстрее и функциональнее чем PHP. Моё внимание остановилось на Ruby.

И собственно вопрос вот какой :

А как в Ruby получить значение полей строки запроса из URL, тоесть из **?s=1&f=2&a=me**, в PHP это было просто получить из массива $_GET, а как сделать это же в Ruby? Подскажите пожалуйста код, как же реализовать такое, и лучше, если он будет полный, тоесть вместе с объявлением класса(если необходимо).

Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: У  Google выходной?)

Comment: А ответить сложно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Identify GET and POST parameters in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/152585/identify-get-and-post-parameters-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Это ведь для рельс, для чистого руби без библиотек с рельсами, можжно такое сделать?

Comment: В ответе выше используется только ruby, если бы использовался RoR, то для контроллера хватило бы вот так: "s = params[s]", аналогично для f и a